# CoreBluetooth XPC Interrupted, resseting

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Sometimes I have a strange log in Xcode : **[CoreBluetooth] XPC connection interrupted, resetting**. At the same time, log in my peripheral shows **Disconnected | REASON: 0x08**. App will not crash after this. Sometimes it will reconnect but then not received notifications or it won't reconnect. Here is full stack trace from iPhone:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9a7d2dbc2d10d0ff30a7bd4bd1178465

After log about XPC sometimes I also have log:

```
[CoreBluetooth] WARNING: <CBPeripheral: 0x1098100d0, identifier = F3D1D63C-CD7B-49E5-ACB0-E4B87F6DB5ED, name = XXXXXXX, state = connecting> is not a valid peripheral
```